# Visual Studio not generating any files to output path

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

When building a solution in VS none of the projects generate dll files even though build is successful. Also build is very fast, kind of scanning project names and outputting them in Output window. My output path is set to `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` depending on build. I tried re-installing VS 2013 both premium and ultimate, nothing seems to work. I also tried different solutions same thing happens in all solutions.
[[image]]

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If project build is successful, then the file should be in directory specified by by "Output Directory" in project property pages. If you cannot locate the files, there are two options:

1. You are looking in the wrong place. Perhaps VS macros are confusing you? Inspect VS output window too see the exact location of the created file in lines like:

`project_name.vcxproj -> path\to\output\directory\library_name.dll`

2. Your project has build events setup, which perform some actions on the output files (for example, it is possible that DLLs are placed into a common archive and deleted afterward, or moved to a common location)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem just today and was able to solve it.

**My circumstances**

I had only one header file in my project, which contained all the source code. I know that this is not the usual way, but I find that Java-like source code structure with both definitions and declarations in the same file is more convenient.

I also think that my problem was concieved when I rearranged all code to be in the header file and deleted source files.

**My solution**

In my .vcxproj-file there was an entry

`<ClInclude Include="TcpExternHdl.hxx" />`

I changed `ClInclude` to `ClCompile`, reloaded the project and everything went back to normal.

**How I found the solution**

When I googled for a solution, i noticed that many people say that after building a solution, in the output window I would get something like

`tcp.ext.vcxproj -> f:\user\source\tcp\..\..\bin\tcp.ext.dll`

and that is where I should look for my files. But there were no such lines in the output. That gave me an idea that something must be wrong with my project file (.vcxproj).

Following that idea, I opened a .vcxproj-file from a solution that was producing .dll-files OK. I compared it with the .vcxproj-file of the problematic solution and found two differences, one of which was a root of the issue.

Btw, I used Notepad++ and Compare plugin to find the differences. Such tools (comparers) really help, I recommend using them.